# Use HTML button to control Arduino

Tags: html, node.js, arduino

I am new to programming with Arduino, Javascript and node.js.

My goal: to control an LED (connected via Arduino Uno) using an HTML button

I have installed johnny-five, an open-source Arduino Javascript framework which allows the user to send commands to an Arduino. When your given Javascript file is run (node example.js), a node command line appears from which commands can be sent.

My question: where should I start if I want to send a Javascript command to this node command line using an HTML button?

I know how to make an html button trigger a function in Javascript, but communicating that through to the Arduino is the part that has me stuck.

If I have said anything above that doesn't make sense, or I am trying something that is impossible, please let me know. Most of all, I want to get an idea of what I need to read/learn in order to make this work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you come right in the end?

Comment: Still learning ajax and the like, so going to hold off on this project for a little bit. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is a server side implementation and html is a client side implementation.

Easiest way is to run an http server (something like the server [here](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server)) on node and then when you click the button in html send a ajax call to the node http server that where you will have access to the node arduino library.